# java anonymous class in enum compilation error

Tags: java, generics, enums, anonymous-inner-class

I could workaround this problem but I cannot understand it, so I am asking for some explanation (and maybe a better question title as well).

Please consider this:

```
public class TBGService {
    // TBGObject is an abstract base class which is extended by model classes
    public <T> T doGet(TBGObject model) throws TBGServiceException {
        String uri = model.buildUrl(repository) + model.getObjectKey();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(uri); 
        T returned = execute(method, credentials, model.getClass());
        return returned;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
public enum TBGTaskAttributes {
    private TBGTaskAttributes(String id, String type, String label, Object... flags) {
        builder = new TaskAttributeBuilder();
        builder.withId(id).withLabel(label);
        for (Object flag : flags) {
            processFlag(flag);
        }
    }

    public abstract String getValueFromIssue(TBGIssue issue);

    public abstract void setValueInIssue(TBGIssue issue, String value);

}
```

when I write this code to define an enum item:

```
PROJECT(TaskAttribute.PRODUCT, TaskAttribute.TYPE_SINGLE_SELECT, "Project", new OptionProvider() {
    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, String>> getOptions(TaskRepository repository) {
        try {
            List<TBGProject> list = TBGService.get(repository)
                .doGet(new TBGProjects()).getProjects();
            [...]
            return map.entrySet();
         } catch (TBGServiceException e) { [...] }
         return null;
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public String getValueFromIssue(TBGIssue issue) {
        return issue.getProjectKey();
    }
    @Override
    public void setValueInIssue(TBGIssue issue, String value) {
        issue.setProjectKey(value);
    }
},
[... other items ...]
```

I get compiler error (also eclipse auto-completion does not work):

```
The method getProjects() is undefined for the type Object
```

and if I hover the doGet method, eclipse show it as defined like:

```
 <Object> Object TBGService.doGet(TBGObject model)
```

Elsewhere, hovering shows the signature correctly as:

```
 <TBGProjects> TBGProjects TBGService.doGet(TBGObject model)
```

when called with parameter `new TBGProjects()`.

Just changing:

```
List<TBGProject> list = TBGService.get(repository)
    .doGet(new TBGProjects()).getProjects();
```

with:

```
TBGProjects projects = TBGService.get(repository).doGet(new TBGProjects());
List<TBGProject> = projects.getProjects();
```

makes it work. But what's happening here? What am I missing?

Comment: BTW, passing a class instance like that is very inefficient.  You should accept a `Class<T>` parameter and pass `TBGProjects.class` instead.

Comment: I see; but actually the passed class contains logic required in abstract superclass. The entry point knows the input for calling the contructor, the service (being a json client) knows nothing about it except the abstract behaviour. Will try to find a better pattern  for this design.

Comment: You may want to use an annotation on the class instead of `getObjectKey()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java infers the type of `T` based on what you assign the return value of the method to.

If you don't assign the return value to anything, Java has no idea what `T` should be.

To fix this, you can change the parameter to be of type `T` so Java can infer `T` from the parameter you pass:

```
public <T extends TBGObject> T doGet(T model) throws TBGServiceException {
```

Comment: oh yeah it was that easy, thanks! and congrats for your quickness in reading and understading someone else code

Comment: side question: why did the same unchanged call work from another class?

Comment: @guido: I don't know why that would work.  Can you show me a complete example in which it compiles?

Comment: sorry my bad; other class is calling a sibling method, in which the parameter is already generic. thanks again

Comment: how do you know the OP intends for the parameter and the return to be the same type?

Comment: @newacct: Because he passes `model.getClass()` to `execute()`, and never uses the parameter elsewhere.